The wedge product of two positive forms is positive

Definition. A real $(p, p)$-form $\psi$ on a complex manifold $M^{n}$ is said to be (semi-) positive, if for any $x \in M$, and any linearly independent $(1,0)$-type tangent vectors $X_{1}, \cdots, X_{p}$ at $x$, it holds
$$(-\sqrt{-1})^{p^{2}} \psi\left(X_{1}, \cdots, X_{p}, \overline{X_{1}}, \cdots, \overline{X_{p}}\right)>0~(\text{or}\geq0)$$
We will denote this by $\psi>0$ (or $\geq 0$).



Exercise 1. For any $(p, 0)$-form $\varphi$, $(\sqrt{-1})^{p^{2}} \varphi \wedge \bar{\varphi} \geq 0$.
Exercise 2. Locally, if we take a frame $\left\{\varphi_{1}, \cdots, \varphi_{n}\right\}$ of $(1,0)$-forms, then any $(p, p)$-form $\psi$ can be expressed as
$$\psi=(\sqrt{-1})^{p^{2}} \sum f_{I \bar{J}} \varphi_{I} \wedge \overline{\varphi_{J}}$$
where $\varphi_{I}=\varphi_{i_{1}} \wedge \cdots \wedge \varphi_{i_{p}}$ if $I=\left\{i_{1}< \cdots< i_{p}\right\}$, and the sum runs through all the multiindices $I \subset\{1, \ldots, n\}$ with $|I|=p$. Denote by $F=\left(f_{I \bar{J}}\right)$ the square matrix. Then $\psi$ is real if and only if $F$ is a Hermitian matrix, and $\psi>0$ (or $\geq 0$) if and only if $F$ is (semi-) positive definite everywhere.
Exercise 3. From the description of exercise 2, show that if $\psi_{1}$ is a positive $(p, p)$-form and $\psi_{2}$ is a positive $(q, q)$-form, then when $p+q\leq n, \psi_{1} \wedge \psi_{2}>0$.

Exercise 1 and 2 are both easy:
$$(-\sqrt{-1})^{p^{2}} (\sqrt{-1})^{p^{2}} \varphi \wedge \bar{\varphi}\left(X_{1}, \cdots, X_{p}, \overline{X_{1}}, \cdots, \overline{X_{p}}\right)$$
$$=\varphi\left(X_{1}, \cdots, X_{p}\right)\cdot\bar{\varphi}\left(\overline{X_{1}}, \cdots, \overline{X_{p}}\right)=\left|\varphi\left(X_{1}, \cdots, X_{p}\right)\right|^2\geq0.$$
So $(\sqrt{-1})^{p^{2}} \varphi \wedge \bar{\varphi} \geq 0$. And
\begin{align*}
&\quad\sum f_{I \bar{J}} \varphi_{I} \wedge \overline{\varphi_{J}}\left(X_{1}, \cdots, X_{p}, \overline{X_{1}}, \cdots, \overline{X_{p}}\right)\\
&=\sum f_{I \bar{J}} \varphi_{I}\left(X_{1}, \cdots, X_{p}\right) \overline{\varphi_{J}}\left( \overline{X_{1}}, \cdots, \overline{X_{p}}\right)\\
&=\sum f_{I \bar{J}} \det\left(\varphi_{i_\alpha}(X_\beta)\right)_{\alpha\beta} \cdot\overline{\det\left(\varphi_{j_\alpha}(X_\beta)\right)_{\alpha\beta}}\\
&=\sum f_{I \bar{J}} \det\left(X_\beta^{i_\alpha}\right)_{\alpha\beta} \cdot\overline{\det\left(X_\beta^{j_\alpha}\right)_{\alpha\beta}}.
\end{align*}
So
$$\psi>0\Leftrightarrow\sum f_{I \bar{J}} \det\left(X_\beta^{i_\alpha}\right)_{\alpha\beta} \cdot\overline{\det\left(X_\beta^{j_\alpha}\right)_{\alpha\beta}}>0\Leftrightarrow\left(f_{I \bar{J}}\right){\rm is~positive~definite}.$$

For exercise 3, write
$$\psi_1=(\sqrt{-1})^{p^{2}} \sum f_{I \bar{J}} \varphi_{I} \wedge \overline{\varphi_{J}}\quad{\rm and}\quad\psi_2=(\sqrt{-1})^{q^{2}} \sum g_{K \bar{L}} \varphi_{K} \wedge \overline{\varphi_{L}},$$
then
\begin{align*}
\psi_1\wedge\psi_2&=(\sqrt{-1})^{p^{2}+q^{2}}\sum_{I,J,K,L}f_{I \bar{J}}g_{K \bar{L}} \varphi_{I} \wedge \overline{\varphi_{J}}\wedge\varphi_{K} \wedge \overline{\varphi_{L}}\\
&=(\sqrt{-1})^{(p+q)^{2}}\sum_{I,J,K,L}f_{I \bar{J}}g_{K \bar{L}} \varphi_{I}\wedge\varphi_{K}  \wedge \overline{\varphi_{J}}\wedge \overline{\varphi_{L}}.
\end{align*}
But note that the sub-scripts of $\varphi_{I}\wedge\varphi_{K}$ may not be arranged in ascending order. If we arrange these sub-scripts from small to large, then what's the matrix? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Can you do it for the product of two positive $(1,1)$-forms, or a positive $(1,1)$-form and a positive $(2,2)$-form?

@JohnnyLemmon I have tried before, but after writing down the matrix, I don't know what to do next. Attempt:$$\sqrt{-1}(a_{ij}\varphi^i\wedge\bar \varphi^j)\wedge\sqrt{-1}(b_{kl}\varphi^k\wedge\bar \varphi^l)=(a_{ij}b_{kl}\varphi^i\wedge \varphi^k\wedge\bar \varphi^j\wedge\bar \varphi^l)$$ $$=\sum_{i<k\j<l}(a_{ij}b_{kl}-a_{kj}b_{il}-a_{il}b_{kj}+a_{kl}b_{ij})\varphi^i\wedge \varphi^k\wedge\bar \varphi^j\wedge\bar \varphi^l.$$

I think we should first fix an order on the space of n-uples, maybe the lexicographic one? Anyway, it seems a cumbersome condition to check.

@JohnnyLemmon I have done it for the wedge product of two positive $(1,1)$-forms. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/479806/the-wedge-product-of-two-positive-forms-is-positive
